# How download .zip/rar archive from github release using libcurl?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have a question that how i can download archive **(.zip/.rar)** from github releases. With simple .html page it works fine, but with github releases not. Strange thin that libcurl returns the `CURL_OK` status from `curl_easy_perform`, but not even try to write any chunk of data.

Here my code:

```cpp
typedef size_t(*CurlWriteDataFn)(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream);

// My write function (simply used from examples)
static size_t CurtWriteData(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

// Donwload function
static void DownloadFile(const std::string& url, const std::string outFilePath, CurlWriteDataFn writeFn) {

    // Check url and outFilePath.
    if (url.empty()) {
        // Curl: URL is not set.
        return;
    }
    if (outFilePath.empty()) {
        // Curl: Output file path is not set.
        return;
    }

    CURL* curl;
    FILE* fp;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        // Curl: Failed to initialize library.
        return;
    }

    // Copying url and outFilepath. (so char* can be always avaliable)
    String _url         = url;
    String _outFilePath = outFilePath;

    fp = fopen(_outFilePath.c_str(), "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        // Curl: Failed to fopen file
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return;
    }

    // Set options for library.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, _url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Dark Secret Ninja/1.0");
    
    // NOTE: Also i try different UserAgents like this: 
    // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"); 
    // but still not work
    
    if (writeFn)
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeFn);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

    // Process donwloading.
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLcode::CURLE_OK) {
        // Curl: Failed to download file.
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
   // -- OK
   // DownloadFile("https://curl.se/mail/lib-2010-11/0182.html", "C:\\MyDownloads\\some.json", CurtWriteData); 
   
   // -- Failed (without any error code)
   DownloadFile("https://github.com/KennyProgrammer/TestRepo/archive/refs/tags/v0.0.1.zip", "C:\\MyDownloads\\SomeRelease-v0.0.1.zip", CurtWriteData);
   
   return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: Also i try to use `url` with **http** not **https** and try to verify **peer** and **host name**,
but sill not work.

```cpp
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L); // verify ssl peer
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L); // verify ssl hostname
```

If there are any suggestions on how to solve this problem? I will be very grateful.

Comment: After `CURLE_OK` you should test `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke curl from command line in verbose mode with `-v` flag to see what's going on

```
curl -v https://github.com/KennyProgrammer/TestRepo/archive/refs/tags/v0.0.1.zip -o 1.zip
```

It shows the server responds with redirect response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
< Location: https://codeload.github.com/KennyProgrammer/TestRepo/zip/refs/tags/v0.0.1
```

You need to to handle it to query actual location url e.g. with [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) option:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

Comment: Yes indeed it is **FOLLOW_LOCATION**. I guessed it by accident yesterday after reading the documentation. It works fine, but I'm not really sure that this is the right decision, because in some of the answers on this topic, people said that it's better not to do this. But as long as it works this solution :) Thank you.

Comment: Only im not sure why people dislike this and post below, technically this is correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Github** issues redirects for downloads, so you need to also set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

When testing the OP code I was unable to get a succesfull download as `curl_easy_perform` was always returning a result code of of `CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION` error.

For some reason my tests also required me to set the following:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

**DISCLAIMER:** However as @273K has commented, It's not recommended to do this as, as per Curl documentation `WARNING: disabling verification of the certificate allows bad guys to man-in-the-middle WARNING: disabling verification of the certificate allows bad guys to man-in-the-middle`

Comment: `true` and `false` are invalid values for those options. They inspire undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @273K I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user20716902 I don't know about others, but setting **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** and **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST** didn't make a difference. Doesn't mean it doesn't need to be used, just for my case it works out without them. Only **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** was required.

Comment: Still not a good answer because of the bad suggestion. Are you willing OP to download a malware?

Comment: @273K And who said that there is malware here? In my opinion, downloading releases from github already guarantees that you will not stumble upon a worm. And besides , the example provides a link that contains .zip archive, which until you open and run what file nothing will happen. (I mean, if someone is worried that it could be malware) In any case, you can use your link to test for security.

Comment: @KennyTutorials W/o a trusted https connection, you are not guaranteed that you download a file from GH. BTW user20716902 is a lady-avenger, paid -2 own rep for getting me -4 rep.

Comment: @273K Well, I use https :) Edit: Well, it's understandable, just if you download something not through a browser, you need to be sure of the reliability of the source.

Comment: @273K, I'm not sure what a "lady-avenger" is, or what your talk about rep is about. I've just tried to provide a good answer and valued and taken on board your comments about my answer and updated my answer accordingly.