# Accessing blob object through a blob URL

Tags: c++, curl, https, blob, httplib

I want to access the blob object from a blob url (url that starts with "blob:https/example.com") in c++ only.

This below is the implementation in JS that I want to imitate in c++:

```
if (url && url.startsWith('blob:')) {
      const fetchblobURL = async function (node, value) {
        let blob = await fetch(value).then(r => r.blob()).then(blob => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
      }
      fetchblobURL(node, attrName, attrValue);
}
```

Any ideas on the implementation using native c++ or libraries will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: As you've tagged c++ and curl, take a look at this question [How to download file using libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466276/how-download-zip-rar-archive-from-github-release-using-libcurl/77467098#77467098) The example code there should meet your requirements